# what is the difference between comprehensive partnership and comprehensive strategic partnership

Tags: foreign-policy

I found these phrases on the Internet. "comprehensive partnership" and "comprehensive strategic partnership"  what is the difference between them?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Politics.SE! Assuming the title is what you meant, there's an extra "strategic" in your question. Also, it would help to have some context; where did you see these phrases used? Could you provide some examples?

Comment: To be honest, like most political-speak, it's largely meaningless and merely intended to make things sound grandiosier than they are. Technically speaking, "strategic" implies longer-term and higher-level goals.